# How to create a tile pointing to dynamic URL in Fiori Launchpad?

Tags: sap-fiori

I want to create a tile, pointing to a dynamic external URL - depending on the system i am clicking the tile.

So for example if I open the tile in my Launchpad on development system, it should open a different URL than by clicking it on productive system.

I've created that tile in the SAP Fiori Launchpad-Designer, but I can only enter a static URL.
Is there a way with some kind of aliases based on system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several mandatory steps to achieve this:

1. Create static app launcher tile
2. Fill in the details with the correct **system alias** (important!)
3. Check "use semantic object navigation" checkbox
4. Create correspondent target mapping with this system alias pointing to app url

This is **source** system alias.

[image]

The final step is to create mappings from this source alias to **target** backend systems in maintenance view `/UI2/V_ALIASMAP`.

Check this tutorial for more details

https://blogs.sap.com/2019/03/20/how-to-create-a-tile-pointing-to-dynamic-url-s4hana/

Comment: Took me a while to figure out that you need to configure an RFC-Destination in transaction `SM59` and add a new System ALIAS in transaction `SPRO` first - but after that It works like a charm - thank you